# Is the SQL LocalDB API deprecated or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb

## Overview

I am developing a C++ application that uses SQL Server LocalDB and I want to avoid making users perform any SQL administration tasks. When my application starts up, it needs to create a named SQL instance "ABC" and then start it. This ensures that the application can later connect to the instance, attach databases and run queries as needed.

## Details

If I were creating and starting the instances manually, I would use SqlLocalDB.exe, the command-line utility described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/command-line-management-tool-sqllocaldb-exe?view=sql-server-ver15). The linked page says this command-line utility is "a simple wrapper around the LocalDB instance API", so my natural thought is that I can use the same underlying API to automate this process. On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/sql-server-express-localdb-reference-instance-apis?view=sql-server-ver15#named-instance-creation), I see that to create a named LocalDB instance, my application should use the "LocalDB management API". There is also [a page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-express-localdb-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) that gives a detailed code sample. Indeed, I have modified the code sample and it works in my application, even using the latest SQL Server LocalDB 2019.

However, note that the code sample includes "sqlncli.h". There is [another page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) that refers to "SQLNCLI" as the "SQL Server Native Client API", and says this API is deprecated and "it is not recommended to use it for new development work".

So, in summary, the recommended way to automate SQL LocalDB instance management is through the SQL LocalDB API, but that API is part of the Native Client API, and the Native Client API is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

## Question

**Is the SQL LocalDB API deprecated or not? And if it is, then what should I use instead?**

My hope is that the LocalDB API is a special, non-deprecated part of the wider Native Client API, but my co-workers and I would appreciate some reassurance about this.

Comment: The answer is in the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) you link: *"**The SQL Server Native Client (SQLNCLI) remains deprecated** and it is not recommended to use it for new development work.*" and goes on to state: *"Instead, use the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) which will be updated with the most recent server features."*

Comment: Of course it is not deprecated...

Comment: If you want reassurance from Microsoft you're arguably barking up the wrong tree regardless, since they have shifted stances multiple times now on which APIs they definitely, positively want to consider deprecated in favor of others (first OLE DB was on the chopping block, then it wasn't, then ODBC was the preferred way for everything, then it wasn't). The most accurate thing anyone can say is that the LocalDB functions are only found in the native client and have no replacement in the OLE DB driver, so if you want to use those you have no choice, deprecation warnings or no.

Comment: I think I'll just go ahead and use it then, it does feel like the best (/only) option. Thanks all for confirming this.